# Div rotate works in JSFiddle but not in the actual project

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to rotate my div 90° on click and than 90° back with the next onclick.

For some reason the rotate didn`t work, so I put the code into a JSFiddle to figure out the problem and suddenly the same code works.

First of all the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YruV7/

Here the code of my project:

**HTML and jQuery:**

```
<script src="resources/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/styles/stylesheet.css" />
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var rotation = 90;

    jQuery.fn.rotate = function(degrees) {
    $(this).css({'-webkit-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                 '-moz-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                 '-ms-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                 'transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)'});
    };

    $( '#control' ).click(function() {   
    $(this).rotate(rotation);
    if( rotation === 90 ) {
        rotation = 0;
    }
    else {
        rotation = 90;
    }
    });
</script>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <div id="mainWrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="control">
            </div>
        </div>
..
```

**CSS:**

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

body,html {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}

div#mainWrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #03436A;
}

div#header {
    background-color: #03436A;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5%;
}

div#control {
    background:url(../images/logo_small.png) no-repeat center center;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
}

div#control:hover {
    opacity: 0.7; 
}
```

I am asking this question because I hope some of you could know some possible cause that the code wouldn't work in my project, or some methods to figure the cause out.

What I am also wondering if there is an easy way to animate the rotate, so that it moves to the right position, instead of being instantly there, but my main question is why the code won't work in my project.

Comment: Add script before closing `body` tag or wrap in `document.ready`.

Comment: Thank you sir, adding the script in the body fixed it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is very simple. When you call `$('#control')`, the element id `control` is yet to exist, because it is declared only after the script, so it fails.

It works in jsFiddle because they call your script in the `window.onload` event when the DOM is already fully loaded.

Answer (score 1):

JS fiddle usually does things for you (like adding the "HTML" tag), so I suspect that you are misplacing the scripts in your project, you should add your script before the end of your body.